# How can I link a test case as a "tested user story" with the Microsoft.TeamFoundation API?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs-2015

I'm writing a console application in C# using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` classes to connect to a Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 on-premises instance.

My application needs to create/upload test cases and link them to existing user stories.
If I use the `RelatedLink` class and add it to the `ITestCase.Links` property, when I view the test case through the web portal, the links appear under the **All Links** tab, and not the **Tested User Stories** tab.

How can I go about linking test cases and stories so that they appear in the **Tested User Stories** tab instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **Link Type** to "`Tested By`".

Try below code sample to link a **test case** to an existing **user story**: (Install the Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/))

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace AssociateWorkitems
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int UserStoryID = 53;
            int TestCaseID = 54;

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs;
            tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://ictfs2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")); 
            tfs.Authenticate();

            var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tfs);
            WorkItem wit = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(UserStoryID);

            //Set "Tested By" as the link type
            var linkTypes = workItemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes;
            WorkItemLinkType testedBy = linkTypes.FirstOrDefault(lt => lt.ForwardEnd.Name == "Tested By");
            WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linkTypeEnd = testedBy.ForwardEnd;

            //Add the link as related link.
            try
            {
                wit.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, TestCaseID));
                wit.Save();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Linked TestCase {0} to UserStory {1}", TestCaseID, UserStoryID));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ignore "duplicate link" errors
                if (!ex.Message.StartsWith("TF26181"))
                    Console.WriteLine("ex: " + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much! That solves the problem :)